# Render partial in other module ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2

In my project I have to modules

- Module1
- Module2

In Module1 I have a view that needs to render a view that I have in Module2, so what I'm doing is:

```
$this->partial('partials/hello/title.phtml','Module2',array('data' => $data))
```

and seems I'm calling correctly the view, but inside of the view title.phtml I'm unable to use data

Undefined variable: data in /site/src/module/Module2/view/partials/hello/title.phtml

Do I need add something related to the configuration?

Thanks!

Comment: I resolved the problem using $data = $this->viewModel()->getCurrent()->data; is this needed when a partial from other modules is used? because until now I was able to use $data because I was using a partial in the same module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't calling it correctly, try:

```
$this->partial('partials/hello/title.phtml', array('data' => $data));
```

See: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.partial.html

The fact that the partial is in a different module doesn't matter. Having to specify the module name as the second parameter was a thing in ZF1 only.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is add your own view-path resolver in module-bootstrap:

```
class Module
{
    /* @var \Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager $SM */
    public static $SM;
    /* @var \Zend\EventManager\EventManager $EM */
    public static $EM; 

    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        self::$SM = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
        self::$EM = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();

        //change view resolver to resolve views from {Module}/view/{Controller}/{Action}.phtml path
        self::$EM->attach('dispatch', function($e) {
            self::$SM->get('ViewRenderer')->resolver()->attach(
                    new \Engine\View\Resolver\MCA() , 10
             );
        });
    }
    ....
```

Resolver gets a string, and must to return path or false (if not resolved), just write resolver to understand other-modules paths:

```
<?php
namespace Engine\View\Resolver;

use Zend\View\Renderer\RendererInterface as Renderer;

/**
 * Resolves view scripts based on a stack of paths
 */
class MCA implements \Zend\View\Resolver\ResolverInterface
{
    public function resolve($name, Renderer $renderer = null)
    {
        $path = explode('/', $name);
        if (count($path)<3){
            return false;
        }
        $module = array_shift($path);
        $resolvedPath = ROOT_PATH . '/module/'. ucfirst($module) . '/view/' . implode('/', $path). '.phtml';
        if (!file_exists($resolvedPath)){
            return false;
        }
        return $resolvedPath;
    }
}
```

There can be collisions, but you can regulate priority of resolvers (10 in example).